# how to filter data based on the creation date into week , month and year till date?

Tags: java, database, date, sqlite

I am new to java programming and I am stuck at the following problem.

I have a database (SQLite3) table in which one of the columns is text which stores `DATE` in the string(text) format. It has to be `Text` for some reasons and not of type `Date` (I even don't know whether Sqlite3 supports date data-type).

Now based on this Text date, I want to filer the data in the table into :

```
 Week : how much data has been entered in the table in this week. 
          Week starts from monday and ends on sunday. 
          So when I filter on week , I want the all the entries that have been 
          entered from Monday to this day of the week.

 Similar results are expected when I want to filter data into month and year.
```

Need some pointers on how this could be done. ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the [date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: Is it possible to do in java code ?I actually want to perform it in my java code

Comment: or in the query through JDBC ? So that I will only get the required data based on whether I have selected week , month or year

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you saying that you have a string in the format like 'MM/DD/YYYY" and you want to extract these dd mm or YYYY values? Please specify the delimiters as well which is there in the string

Comment: yes , in my database table there is column which stores date in string format as 'mm/dd/yyyy' and now i want to get the only those tuples through sql query which have been created in this week , month or year.

Comment: one query will bring in all the tuples created in this week ,
other in this month and the third one will bring data of this year based upon the values in that column

Comment: now.get will give me the string value of the current date ?what will the function return? will it be useful for week?

Comment: Your question is confusing because you do state exactly what is stored in your database. Exactly what values do you store in exactly what [SQLite data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)? You seem to be confusing the stored date-time value with its textual representation in any of many various formats. Be clear about when you are speaking of SQLite data types and when you are speaking of Java/JDBC data types.

Answer (score 0):

I will give an example for the week. You can use similar technique for month and year. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE yourTimestamp >= CURDATE() - LEAST(6, DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-2)
```

DAYOFWEEK() numbers Sunday as 1, Saturday as 7. What happens if the command is run on a Sunday? To cater for this, LEAST(6,...) is used.

Comment: If yourTimestamp is a string, then do this: STR_TO_DATE(yourTsString,'%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: did not get you? Where in the query that you have provided should i add this?

Comment: STR_TO_DATE() no such function: this is the error I am getting

Comment: I think I understand your issue. You must be using Sqlite rather than Sql. Sqlite does not have STR_TO_DATE(). You have to look up Sqlite manual.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is to use the java.Util.Calendar library to create your query from the db layer of your code.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH); // Note: zero based!    
int dayofMonth = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

But the trickiest part in forming this query from java layer is to get the number of days elapsed since the first day of the week,
For this you need to use 
    int dayofWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

// If current day is Sunday, day=1. Saturday, day=7.

The following function can return a String array of the elapsed days in week -

```
String[] elapsedDaysOfWeek(String dayOfWeek,String dayofMonth)
{
int dayOfWeek=Int.ParseInt(dayOfWeek);
int dayOfMonth=IntParseInt(dayOfMonth);

String[] days=new String(dayOfWeek);

days[0]=dayOfMonth;
for (int i=1;i<dayOfWeek;i++)
days[i]=(dayOfMonth-i).ToString();

return days;
}
```

So if you call elapsedDaysOfWeek(5,25) - you will get an arry of {25,24,23,22,21} - this array you can use in your query using an ÍN' keyword -
e.g. substr(datetext,1,2) in {25,24,23,22,21}